# Texture mapping complex procedural meshes

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js, uv-mapping

I'm working on a Three JS project that creates procedurally generated meshes at run-time.

I need to apply texture-mapping to these shapes. For simple shapes with a definite top, bottom and sides, I understand I can use planar-mapping which is fine.

However, What about more complex shapes e.g. a torus knot? For example, I want it to look like there is grass on the 'top' and rocky at the 'bottom'.

I want to apply the texturing so there are no obvious seams, I'm not too worried about stretching as I'm not looking for super-realism.

Also, I'd rather not have use shaders that blend multiple textures.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Creating the texture coordinates together with the geometry is always better than forcing artificial UVs onto it afterwards. The torus knot could be modeled with the UVs of a cylinder. If you don't want to blend textures in a shader, you can blend them on the CPU. Once you have the texture coordinates, find out the parts of the textures that should be rock and which should be grass and create a texture with those properties.